# Delete the json object recursively using id

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I wanted to delete the entire json Object if it matches the id, thus keep the structure of the json consistent. My sample json looks something like this:

```js
{
 "menu": {
  "id": "1",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
   "children": [{
     "value": "New",
     "onclick": "Some click value",
     "id": "2"
    },
    {
     "value": "Open",
     "onclick": "OpenDoc()",
     "id": "3"
    },
    {
     "value": "Close",
     "onclick": "CloseDoc()",
     "id": "4"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

I want to delete the entire object if the id matches. My code looks something like this

```js
static deleteJsonObject(myJson, objectId) {
    for(var key in myJson) {
      if (_.isArray(myJson[key])) {
        if(myJson[key].length == 0) {
          return
        }
        if(objectId == myJson['id']) {
          delete myJson[key]
        }
        
        this.deleteJsonObject(myJson[key], objectId);
      } else if (_.isObject(myJson[key])) {
        if(objectId == myJson['id']) {
          delete myJson[key]
        }
        this.deleteJsonObject(myJson[key], objectId);
      } 
      else if (_.isString(myJson[key])) {
        if(objectId == myJson['id']) {
          delete myJson[key]
        }
      }
    }
    return myJson
  }
```

The problem with my code is that it just deletes the id rather than the entire object if its a child element. Any help is appreciated. Note that I dont want to have empty objects after deletion. It should remove the object entirely from the json. No empty objects or null objects.

Comment: Could you please read the usage description of the `json` tag?

Answer (score 0):

A safe way to accomplish what you want is to perform a [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) in your tree, deleting the whole object if the id match.

```js
const data = {
    "menu": {
        "id": "1",
        "value": "File",
        "popup": {
            "children": [{
                    "value": "New",
                    "onclick": "Some click value",
                    "id": "2"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Open",
                    "onclick": "OpenDoc()",
                    "id": "3"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Close",
                    "onclick": "CloseDoc()",
                    "id": "4"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

const deleteByID = (tree, id) =>
{
    // First we iterate every element of the object
    for (const key in tree)
    {
        const node = tree[key]

        // If the element id matches we delete the whole element
        if (node.id == id)
        {
            // If the parent of this element is a Array, we must remove it with splice
            if (tree instanceof Array)
            {
                tree.splice(key, 1)
            }
            // Else, we can use the delete operator to delete the property
            else
            {
                delete tree[key]
            }
        }
        // If the element id don't match (or the element doesn't have a id property), we recursively iterate all it's properties
        else if (typeof node === 'object')
        {
            deleteByID(node, id)
        }
    }
}

deleteByID(data, 3)

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var obj = {
 "menu": {
  "id": "1",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
   "children": [{
     "value": "New",
     "onclick": "Some click value",
     "id": "2"
    },
    {
     "value": "Open",
     "onclick": "OpenDoc()",
     "id": "3"
    },
    {
     "value": "Close",
     "onclick": "CloseDoc()",
     "id": "4"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
};

var id = "2";

function deleteObject(obj, id) {
 if (obj.menu.id === id) {
   delete obj.menu;
  } else if (Object.keys(obj.menu).includes('popup')) {
   var result = obj.menu.popup.children.filter(item => {
     if (item.id === id) {
       obj.menu.popup.children.splice(obj.menu.popup.children.indexOf(item), 1);
      }
    });
  }
  return obj;
}

var res = deleteObject(obj, id);

console.log(res);
```